# How to print email body data before send email in magento 2

Tags: magento2

How to print email body data before send email i am working on local i want see the email data what data is going on email 
i tried to print `$transport` but its not working can someone please let me know how we can trying email data

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**To display the email data before sending**.

> **Go to** - **vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php**

Function name - **prepareMessage**
**line no 412** - below line 412 add below code :

```
echo $content;

exit;
```

> After that clear cache and do any action from where email is fired it
> will print email details.

Comment: no luck @manthan

Comment: @Markhenry - Are you using community edition right ? - its working and i am using it for debug purpose. which version you are using ?

Comment: magento version  :2.1.4

Comment: i am able to print body now but order items its not showing in body why ?

Comment: i made it work thanks for the path that linked to my issue

Comment: Happy to help and keep helping :)

Answer (score 7):

`Magento\Email\Model\Transport:: sendMessage()` line  94 adding

```
echo quoted_printable_decode($this->message ->getBodyText());
die;
```

We can able to print email template in Magento 2.3

Answer (score 3):

For all those facing this issue, they can use

```
echo $template->processTemplate(); die;
```

in the file **prepareMessage()** function that will be around 378 line number in

```
vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder
```

This is tested and working for Magento version 2.3.5-p1

Comment: i am able to print body now. Thanks  @vivek

Answer (score 1):

You can print the email text from file : **vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php**

In `Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder:: prepareMessage()`

`echo $template->processTemplate(); die;`